# Failed to install unpublished add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-workspace, gmail-addons

I have an unpublished gmail add-on. I used to test it with installing the add-on to my private Gmail account. It worked perfectly before.
Recently the installation stopped working. Here is how it looks:

1. I am going to my project at https://script.google.com/
2. I choose in the menu 'Publish' -> 'Deploy from manifest'
3. I uninstall the previous add-on version, then I install the new one.
4. I refresh my Gmail inbox page but the add-on does not appear on the right side bar. Also I went to Gmail settings and checked whether the add-on was installed - and I found that it wasn't.
5. I retried the installation multiple times during a week and it still does not work.

Does anybody have idea how to fix that?

Thank you, guys!

P.S. Please find manifest here:

```
{
  "exceptionLogging": "CLOUD",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
    "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zixia/gast/master/src/gas-tap-lib.js",
"https://linkedin.com/search"
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "LinkedIn assistant",
    "logoUrl": "https://pngimg.com/uploads/linkedIn/linkedIn_PNG39.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {},
      "onTriggerFunction": "handleShowCard"
    }],
    "universalActions": [{
      "text": "Email to support",
      "openLink": "TODO"
    }],
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://www.linkedin.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Most likely there is something wrong with your manifest, but hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: @ziganotschka Thank you I added the manifest above

Comment: It looks ok - provided it contains all the scopes your code might need. If you are sure that your code worked before and you did not change anything - I can only recommend you to create the Add-on again in a new project .